# MYSQL query to Get Department Names who all are having number of employee grater than 10

Tags: mysql

MYSQL query to Get Department Names who all  are having number of employee grater than 10.

Should be optimized query and should execute faster.

Comment: `select Name from Departments where number_of_employee > 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dept.name, COUNT(employee.id) as empcount 
from dept INNER JOIN employee ON dept.id = employee.deptId 
GROUP BY dept.id 
HAVING empcount > 10;
```